# iPhone safari capabilities for sauce labs in selenium

Tags: iphone, selenium-webdriver, safari, saucelabs

I need your help to resolve following issue for iPhone safari capabilities for sauce-labs.
I am using iPhone safari to test my application in mobile web.
Manually its working in iPhone safari, i.e. When I click a link its opening new tab(window) manually in sauce-labs.
The same is not working in automation. When I click a link it should open in a new tab(window), but in automation, its not opening in new window/same window.

Note: Observed that popup is opened and asking to select options from it. how to disable this popup through capabilities and open link in new window/tab.

Currently I am using following capabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.iphone();
caps.setCapability("username", sauceUserName);
caps.setCapability("accessKey", sauceAccessKey);
caps.setCapability("appiumVersion", "1.17.1");
caps.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone XS Simulator");
caps.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
caps.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "13.4");
caps.setCapability("browserName", "Safari");
caps.setCapability("browserVersion", "13.4");
caps.setCapability("screenResolution", "1024X768");
webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(sauceURL), caps);
```

Please see the [attached snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBGTh.png)

Comment: can you please share the code that you are using to actually click the link? The code that you shared is only starting a session. Also, please share a screenshot of the HTML code that is relevant to this link so that we can see how the code written corresponds to the HTML in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

able to resolve the issue by adding the below capabilities

caps.setCapability("safariAllowPopups", true);
caps.setCapability("safariOpenLinksInBackground", true);